# Vue 3 - reactive array of objects has wrong behavior when removing single object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm building at the moment a list, where I can add and remove Items.
My problem is when I'm calling `ListManager.close(item)` from my **List Helper**, only the first item is removed regardless of which item I add to the close function.

At the end of the `close(item) {}` function is a `console.log(this.list)` where the correct result is returned. But the **List Component** removes only the first item.

The `ListManager.list`contains an array of objects.

**List Helper**

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const ListManager = reactive({
    list: [],
    add(item) {
        this.list.push(item);
    },
    close(item) {

        this.list = this.list.filter(function (el) {
            return el != item;
        });

        console.log(this.list);

    },

});
```

**List Component**

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <list-item :item="item" v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index" />
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { toRef } from "vue";
import { ListManager } from "./";

export default {
    name: "list",
    setup() {
        const list = toRef(ListManager, "list");

        return {
            list
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does *List Component removes only the first item* mean it always removes the first item, not correct item? Or do you mean it works the first time, but never again?

Comment: @Bravo yes, it means it always removes the first item, not correct item.

Comment: that's odd. What's also odd is that I've never seen functions in an object passed to `Reactive` - perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: @Bravo I tried to add the reactive only to the list: ``list: reactive([]),``,  the results are correct. But now the **List Component** no longer removes any item, I think that has to do with the ``const list = toRef(ListManager, "list");``?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm not upgrading to Vue3 until there's some decent libraries for it

Answer (score 0):

Using methods inside `reactive` like doing in normal classes looks like a bad approach since `reactive` takes an object as parameter and behaves as state, the best approach is to use composable functions which works fine with composition API :

**useList.js**

```
import {reactive,toRef} from 'vue'

export default function useList(){
   const state= reactive({list: []});

     function  add(item) {
        state.list.push(item);
    }
  
    function  close(item) {
        state.list = state.list.filter(function (el) {
            return el != item;
        });
        console.log(state.list);
     }

   return {list:toRef(state, 'list'),add,close}
}
```

in the component ;

```
<script>
import { toRef } from "vue";
import useList from "./useList";

export default {
    name: "list",
    setup() {
        const {list,add,close} = useList();
       //or const ListManager=useList()
       //then you could do ListManager.add(5) and ListManager.list.value

        return {
            list,add,close
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a better approach. But when I'm using the ``const {list,add,close} = useList();``, nothing happens in the template. The component does not see that list has changed.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. The ``const state= reactive({list: []});`` has to be outside of the function.

Comment: But the problem that everytime the first item gets removed keeps the same.

Comment: setting that outside of the function is not solution please show me how do you use/manipulate the state inside the template